# C# Add days to a given date

Tags: c#, datetime, console, console-application, leap-year

I got fairly simple exercise to do on first look but it ended up being quite hard instead. I need to take a date as an input and also add days to the it which are also taken from the user input. I already did some functions and some simple calculations and now i have all the days taken from the date (01,01,0001 is zero) for example :

first January second year (01.01.0002) + 0 days is equal to 365 days it also calculates correctly if i add some days to it : 01.01.0002 + 12 days = 387.. it calculates leap years too. Now that i have totalDays i just need to convert it into a normal Day/Month/Year format..

**IM NOT ALLOWED TO USE DATETIME**

Here's my code :

```
private static int[] daysPerMonth = new int[12];
    private static int days;
    private static int months;
    private static int years;
    private static int add;

    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter day : ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out days);
        Console.Write("Enter Month : ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out months);
        Console.Write("Enter Year : ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out years);
        Console.Write("Enter days to add : ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out add);
        int totalDays = GetTotalDays(new[] {days, months, years});
        totalDays += add;
        TransformIntoDate(totalDays);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void TransformIntoDate(int inputDays)
    {

    }
    private static int GetTotalDays(IReadOnlyList<int> date)
    {
        int totalDays = 0;
        for (int i = date[2]; i > 1; i--)
        {
            if (IsLeap(i))
            {
                daysPerMonth = new[] {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
                totalDays += 366;
            }
            else
            {
                daysPerMonth = new[] {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
                totalDays += 365;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= date[1]; i++)
        {
            if (i == date[1])
            {
                totalDays += date[0] - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                totalDays += daysPerMonth[i];
            }
        }
        return totalDays;
    }

    private static bool IsLeap(int year)
    {
        if (year%400 == 0) return true;
        return (year%4 == 0) && (year%100 != 0);
    }
```

Comment: *GetTotalDays(new[] {days, months, years})* Don't. Please. Don't put three totally disconnected numbers in an array. They are three parameters that should have names, like *year*, *month*, *day*, not `date[2]`, `date[1]`, `date[0]`

Comment: I was planning to create enum for them but i didn't

Comment: Create a class or structure to hold the data and do the calcs.  Maybe you cant *use* DateTime but you can mimic what it does

Comment: I dont know how to do the calcs and i'm trying to reproduce the function of dateTime but i cant seem to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to "save" a date: saving separately year, month, day or saving the total number of days (or hours or minutes or seconds or milliseconds... Select an unit of measure here) from the "0 point". The `DateTime` of .NET for example uses 100 nanoseconds as the `Tick`, and 1 january 0001 as the "0 point". Unix uses seconds from 1 january 1970. Clearly the way of .NET and of Unix is more compact in memory (a single value to save) and is very useful if you want to add/subtract a quantity (simply add/subtract it). The problem is that it is more complex to convert this internal number to year/month/day or to convert a year/month/day to this number.

A simple example on how the year/month/day to internal number can be done:

```
public class MyDate
{
    public int TotalDaysFrom00010101 { get; private set; }

    private const int DaysIn400YearCycle = 365 * 400 + 97;
    private const int DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400 = 365 * 100 + 24;
    private const int DaysIn4YearCycle = 365 * 4 + 1;

    private static readonly int[] DaysPerMonthNonLeap = new[] 
    {
        31, 
        31 + 28, 
        31 + 28 + 31, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30, 
        31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 // Useless
    };

    private static readonly int[] DaysPerMonthLeap = new[] 
    {
        31, 
        31 + 29, 
        31 + 29 + 31, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30, 
        31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 // Useless
    };

    public static bool IsLeap(int year)
    {
        if (year % 400 == 0) return true;
        return (year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0);
    }

    public void SetDate(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        TotalDaysFrom00010101 = 0;

        {
            int year2 = year - 1;

            // Full 400 year cycles
            TotalDaysFrom00010101 += (year2 / 400) * DaysIn400YearCycle;
            year2 %= 400;

            // Remaining 100 year cycles (0...3)
            if (year2 >= 100)
            {
                year2 -= 100;
                TotalDaysFrom00010101 += DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400;

                if (year2 >= 100)
                {
                    year2 -= 100;
                    TotalDaysFrom00010101 += DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400;

                    if (year2 >= 100)
                    {
                        year2 -= 100;
                        TotalDaysFrom00010101 += DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Full 4 year cycles
            TotalDaysFrom00010101 += (year2 / 4) * DaysIn4YearCycle;
            year2 %= 4;

            // Remaining non-leap years
            TotalDaysFrom00010101 += year2 * 365;
        }

        // Days from the previous month
        if (month > 1)
        {
            // -2 is because -1 is for the 1 January == 0 index, plus -1 
            // because we must add only the previous full months here. 
            // So if the date is 1 March 2016, we must add the days of 
            // January + February, so month 3 becomes index 1.
            TotalDaysFrom00010101 += DaysPerMonthNonLeap[month - 2];

            if (month > 2 && IsLeap(year))
            {
                TotalDaysFrom00010101 += 1;
            }
        }

        // Days (note that the "instant 0" in this class is day 1, so
        // we must add day - 1)
        TotalDaysFrom00010101 += day - 1;
    }

    public void GetDate(out int year, out int month, out int day)
    {
        int days = TotalDaysFrom00010101;

        // year
        {
            year = days / DaysIn400YearCycle * 400;
            days %= DaysIn400YearCycle;

            if (days >= DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400)
            {
                year += 100;
                days -= DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400;

                if (days >= DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400)
                {
                    year += 100;
                    days -= DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400;

                    if (days >= DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400)
                    {
                        year += 100;
                        days -= DaysIn100YearCycleNotDivisibleBy400;
                    }
                }
            }

            year += days / DaysIn4YearCycle * 4;
            days %= DaysIn4YearCycle;

            // Special case: 31 dec of a leap year
            if (days != 1460)
            {
                year += days / 365;
                days %= 365;
            }
            else
            {
                year += 3;
                days = 365;
            }

            year++;
        }

        // month
        {
            bool isLeap = IsLeap(year);

            int[] daysPerMonth = isLeap ? DaysPerMonthLeap : DaysPerMonthNonLeap;

            for (month = 0; month < daysPerMonth.Length; month++)
            {
                if (daysPerMonth[month] > days)
                {
                    if (month > 0)
                    {
                        days -= daysPerMonth[month - 1];
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            month++;
        }

        // day
        {
            day = days;
            day++;
        }
    }

    public void AddDays(int days)
    {
        TotalDaysFrom00010101 += days;
    }
}
```

The point here is that we know that there are "periods" of 400 years, and each one of these "cycles" has `365 * 400 + 97` days. After subtracting these "cycles" there are smaller "cycles" of 100 years, each one with `365 * 100 + 24` days. Then we have "cycles" of 4 years, each one with `365 * 4 + 3` days, plus the remaining years (0...3) each one with 365 days.

After having added the days for all the "full previous years", we can add the days for the "full previous months". Here we must consider the possibility that the year is a leap year.

And in the end we add the selected day.

How to write the `GetDate()` is left as an exercise.

Now... How can I check if the result is correct? We could write some unit tests based on the `DateTime` implementation... Something like:

```
var date = default(DateTime);
var endDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);

while (date < endDate)
{
    int year = date.Year;
    int month = date.Month;
    int day = date.Day;

    int totalDays = (int)(date - default(DateTime)).TotalDays;

    var md = new MyDate();
    md.SetDate(year, month, day);

    if (totalDays != md.TotalDaysFrom00010101)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:d}: {1} vs {2}", date, totalDays, md.TotalDaysFrom00010101);
    }

    int year2, month2, day2;
    md.GetDate(out year2, out month2, out day2);

    if (year != year2 || month != month2 || day != day2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:d}: {1:D4}-{2:D2}-{3:D2} vs {4:D4}-{5:D2}-{6:D2}", date, year, month, day, year2, month2, day2);
    }

    date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

(I do know that this isn't a unit test... but shows how to use `DateTime` to do a comparison)

Note that this is an example on how to implement it. I wouldn't implement it this way. I would make an immutable `struct` like `DateTime`, with a constructor instead of a `SetDate()`. But yours seems to be an exercise, and I do think that one should proceed by small steps: first build correctly something, then make it "formally correct". So the first step is building a correct `GetDate()`/`SetDate()`, then you can encapsulate correctly in a more formally correct data structure. This small sample is even missing some parameter validation: you can `SetDate(-1, 13, 32)` :-)

The `GetDate()` was quite complex to build. Much more than I thought. Finally I was able to comprehend how to write it. Note that in the end it is quite similar to the implementation of Microsoft (see [`GetDatePart(int part)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,ff06f271f088f1a8,references).

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer but did you leave the part where i need to convert days into year up to me ? Im still trying to understand the code (im beginner in c#) and im kinda confused what we get from SetDate is just the days right ? I also had similar implementation posted in my question and my problem was exactly converting the days into day/month/year

Comment: The `SetDate()` is complete and works correctly. The `AddDays()` is complete and works correctly. What is missing is something to convert the internal day number (`TotalDaysFrom00010101`) to a year/month/day (something that is done in `GetDate()`). But given a working `SetDate()` it should be feasible to do it (even because it is very easy to test... Do a `SetDate()` of a date and try to obtain it back with `GetDate()`

Comment: Why is GetDate taking year,month,day as a parameter isn't it supposed to take only days and give back year,month,day ?

Comment: @KOPEUE Because the total number of days is a field of `MyClass`, so `GetDate()` can use it.

Comment: I'm so lost in your code im sorry i cant make it work i will upvote it for your effort tho